# O que é um operador binário

Tags: bash, shell-script

Fiz um código em bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Digite o arquivo: "
read ARQUIVO
PROCURA=$(find /home/gabriel -name $ARQUIVO)
test $PROCURA -e & echo "O arquivo '$ARQUIVO' não foi encontrado"
```

E ao executa-lo aparece a seguinte mensagem de erro mencionando operadores binários:

```
prompt$./testa-arquivos.sh 

Digite o arquivo: 
teste
O aruqivo 'teste' não foi encontrado
./testa-arquivos.sh: linha 6: test: Script/teste: esperado operador binário
```

Como posso resolver esse erro, e também gostaria de entender o que são operadores binários e para o que servem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Operador binário é aquele que recebe dois operandos. E isso pode ser uma dor em Bash.

Algo que eu costumo e muito é verificar se um número é maior do que ou igual a outro. Para isso, eu uso o `test` com o operador `gt`:

```
if [ "$numero" -gt 2 ]; then
    ...
fi
```

Onde podem surgir os principais gargalos com operadores binários em Bash? Bem, além da sintaxe com comportamentos bem fora do padrão (de quem vem dum mundo mais comportado como C, Java ou Pascal), temos as tais das expansões de variáveis.

O que são essas tais das expansões? Bem, percebeu que eu coloquei aspas ao redor de `$numero`? Eu fiz isso com um único objetivo: se não tiver valor em `$numero`, coloque a string vazia.

Imagine um cenário em que não `$numero` não tem valor; ao fazer a expansão da variável, o meu código ficaria assim:

```
if [ "" -gt 2 ]; then
    ...
fi
```

Agora imagine que eu tivesse esquecido das aspas. O meu código seria expandido para o seguinte:

```
if [  -gt 2 ]; then
    ...
fi
```

Note que, nesse segundo caso, não há mais operador ao lado esquerdo de `-gt`, o que ocasiona num erro de comparação!

O outro ponto que eu falei foi referente a sintaxe fora do padrão. Se você não tomar cuidado, um curto-circuito de comandos pode acabar se transformando na chamada de uma rotina em paralelo ou na abertura de um pipeline.

Por exemplo, o operador de curto circuito **AND** `&&` indica que eu só executo o comando à direita se o comando à esquerda retornar `true` (no mundo shell, código de saída 0). O operador de curto circuito **OR** `||` indica que eu só executo o comando à direita se o comando à esquerda retornar `false` (no mundo shell, código de saída diferente de 0).

Então, vamos para os operadores de processamento paralelo e pipeline. O operador `&` indica que o comando que o procede precisa ser executado em paralelo; perceba que um simples erro de digitação pode transformar o **AND** `&&` nesse operador. Já o operador `|` vai criar um pipeline entre o comando à esquerda e o comando à direita; note que é fácil errar a digitação do **OR** `||` e cair no pipe.

Note que, no seu código, o comando `test` está sendo executado em outra thread, pois ele vem seguido do `&`.

Para mais leituras, consulte o [Canivete Suíço do Shell Script](http://aurelio.net/shell/canivete/) por Aurélio Verde

Answer (score 1):

Respondendo a sua pergunta, de maneira mais simples.

Troque a linha:

```
test $PROCURA -e & echo "O aruqivo '$ARQUIVO' não foi encontrado"
```

Pelo trecho abaixo :

```
if [  -e $PROCURA ]; then
echo 'O arquivo foi encontrado.'
else
echo 'O arquivo não foi encontrado'
fi
```

Bem agora vamos falar sobre o porque da mensagem de erro na linha, na sua linha de teste o `-e` (operador binário) veio depois da variável, ela deveria vir antes, mas mesmo assim a sua linha não iria funcionar do jeito que estava, pois você precisaria de uma estrutura que valida-se o teste. O teste só testa, ele não tem ação alguma, você precisa do `if` para pegar o resultado do teste e torná-lo em uma condição de verdadeiro ou falso.

Agora vem a explicação longa, mas primeiro vamos falando comando test. você se perguntou porque estamos usando o `[` e não escrevendo `test`?

Pois bem, eles são as mesmas coisa. Na realidade, existe 3 comando test, um nativo do bash, `/usr/bin/test` e `/usr/bin/[`. Mas existem diferenças entre eles relacionadas a POSIX. É bem complexo explicar essa diferenças, mas por hora se seu script der problema com `[` você terá que usá-lo de forma colchetes duplo `[[`.

Os operadores binários são aqueles que você determina na hora do test, como `-e` (existe), `-f` (arquivo) , `-d` (diretório) e etc. consulte a *man page* do bash para ver todos.

Agora vai uma dica extra sobre operadores logicos:

Use `-a` para "e" logico e `-o` para "ou" logico, talvez por causa de parâmetros da POSIX os operadores `&&` e `||` não sejam interpretado pelo bash. Mas ainda pode usar existe aquela opção de colchete duplos `[[`.

Espero que tenha ficado claro para você.

Comment: Discordo da explicação sobre _se seu script der problema com "[" você terá que usá-lo de forma colchetes duplo "[["_. Colchetes duplos são voltados para interpretação mais literal do que está escrito, sem precisar se prender as idiossincrasias do `bash`