# Interpretação sobre operadores lógicos em Java quanto ao curto-circuito

Tags: java, operadores, curto-circuito

Li essa pergunta [Dúvida sobre operadores lógicos && e || em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/303595/d%C3%BAvida-sobre-operadores-l%C3%B3gicos-e-em-java), porém sigo com a dúvida. Resolvendo alguns exercícios sobre Java encontro tal afirmativa:

> Os operadores & e | funcionam de forma idêntica aos operadores && e
>   ||, mas sempre avaliam ambos os operandos.

A resposta diz que a afirmativa está **CORRETA**, porém meu questionamento é:

1. No caso da citação acima, sempre iremos avaliar ambos os operandos?
2. Os operadores || e && não geram [curto-circuito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/204923/o-que-%C3%A9-um-operador-bin%C3%A1rio/204950#204950)? E com isso NÃO FUNCIONAM DE FORMA IDÊNTICA ou estou cometendo algum erro de interpretação?

Comment: Note que o que você linkou foi uma resposta sobre shell script que menciona brevemente o curto circuito. O entendimento daquela resposta deve ser tomada com uns grãos de sal para extrapolar pra Java

Comment: Percebi isso! Mas foi a busca mais coerente que encontrei buscando a palavra 'curto-circuito', mas os links que o Maniero postou deixou mais claro o curto circuito!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> No caso da citação acima, sempre iremos avaliar ambos os operandos?

Não, a diferença mais visível é justamente esta. Usando `&&` e `||` há o chamado curto-circuito, ou sejam se a expressão da esquerda se mostrar suficiente (verdeiro quando usa-se `||`; ou falso quando usa-se `&&`) a expressão da direita sequer é executada. Já com `&` e `|` as duas expressões são executadas, mesmo que não precisa para dar o resultado desejado.

> Os operadores || e && não geram [curto-circuito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/204950/101)?

Exatamente o oposto eles geram, e esse *link* nada tem a ver com curto circuito. [Este tem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190579/101). E [este também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/224468/101).

> E com isso NÃO FUNCIONAM DE FORMA IDÊNTICA ou estou cometendo algum erro de interpretação?

Não funcionam de forma idêntica, o texto que leu é mal escrito. Ele afirma algo para negar em seguida. Não sei onde achou isso, mas escolha bem suas fontes, algumas pessoas não tem compromisso com o correto. A outra resposta também está errada porque afirma que os dois funcionam igual no texto e nos exemplos inverte o que está afirmando e dá resultados errados.

Na verdade esta nem é a única diferença. Os operadores `&` e `|` nem são lógicos são manipuladores de bits, só que se o valor for booleano o resultado acaba sendo o mesmo porque ele só tem 1 bit que importa.

Assim dá para ver melhor o que executa e o resultado que dá:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (teste("1", false) & teste("2", true)) System.out.println("false & true entrou");
        if (teste("3", false) && teste("4", true)) System.out.println("false && true entrou");
        if (teste("5", true) & teste("6", false)) System.out.println("true & false entrou");
        if (teste("7", true) && teste("8", false)) System.out.println("true && false entrou");
        if (teste("9", false) | teste("10", true)) System.out.println("false | true entrou");
        if (teste("11", false) || teste("12", true)) System.out.println("false || true entrou");
        if (teste("13", true) | teste("14", false)) System.out.println("true | false entrou");
        if (teste("15", true) || teste("16", false)) System.out.println("true || false entrou");
    }
    public static boolean teste(String mensagem, boolean valor) {
        System.out.println(mensagem);
        return valor;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/mB91Uw). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/holptmly-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Syntax/ShortCircuit.java).