# Quando usar if ou else If?

Tags: c#, if, lógica, else

É uma coisa bem boba, mas durante minha escrita me deparei com a seguinte dúvida: Quando é realmente necessário usar `if`'s ou `else if`'s no meu código? Existe algum impacto em desempenho?

Vou colocar abaixo o exemplo da onde essa dúvida me surgiu.

```
@if (item.Recursos == "Usuario") //Se o tipo de recurso for "Usuario", ele vai perguntar qual foi o usuário criado antes de finalizar
{
    <p style="font-size: 14px; font-weight:bold;">Usuario Criado:</p>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UsuarioCriado, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
}

@if (item.Recursos == "E-mail") //Se o tipo de recurso for "Emmail", ele vai perguntar qual foi o e-mail criado antes de finalizar
{
    <p style="font-size: 14px; font-weight:bold;">E-mail Criado:</p>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailCriado, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
}

@if (item.Recursos == "Desktop" || item.Recursos == "Desktop (Novo") //Se o tipo de recurso for "Desktop" ou "Desktop (Novo)", ele vai perguntar qual o nome/número da maquina antes de finalizar
{
    <p style="font-size: 14px; font-weight:bold;">Nome do Desktop:</p>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NomeDesktop, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
}

@if (item.Recursos == "Notebook") //Se o tipo de recurso for "Notebook", ele vai perguntar qual o nome/número da maquina antes de finalizar
{
    <p style="font-size: 14px; font-weight:bold;">Nome do Notebook:</p>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NomeNotebook, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## TL; DR

Quando você usa um `else` está dizendo que ele só deve ser avaliado se um `if` anterior for falso. Se um `if` anterior for verdadeiro todos os `else` seguintes serão ignorados.

Entenda que avaliar é verificar a condição, não é executar o bloco de comandos que só ocorrerá se aquela condição específica for verdadeira.

Não faz diferença se o `else` tem um `if` junto ou não, o `else` sozinho é como se tivesse um `if (true)` implícito.

## Explicando melhor

A questão na verdade é sobre usar o `else`. Ele deve ser usado sempre que você quer que aconteça depois de eliminar uma condição possível, ou seja, você quer testar algo excluindo o que já foi testado que você já sabe que não é aquela condição. É como um sistema de *knockout* onde alguma a coisa sai da jogada porque não atingiu uma determinada marca. O `else` é usado quando há condições **mutualmente exclusivas**.

O `else` sozinho significa que a condição é qualquer coisa desde que não seja o que já determinou a(s) condição(ões) anterior(es). Quando tem um `else` depois de apenas um `if` você tem uma situação binária, ou é uma coisa ou é o oposto dessa condição. QUando tem vários `if` (obviamente com um `else` junto depois do primeiro), o `else` ainda pode ser considerado uma situação binária, ou seja, é ele se todas as outras juntas falharem.

Em geral quando você usa `vários` else` juntos é porque as condições são muito semelhantes e estão testando a mesma coisa com valores diferentes, pode ser uma faixa de valores por exemplo.

Agora vamos pegar seu exemplo como caso concreto para demonstrar. O `if` inicial verifica se `item.Recursos` tem como valor o texto `Usuario`. Se ele tiver esse texto, ou seja, a condição é verdadeira, ele entra no bloco e executa o que foi determinado, certo? Aí vamos para o próximo `if`. Ele também verifica o conteúdo de `item.Recursos`. Se ele tem aquele valor inicialmente testado, ele pode ter outro valor? Não, né? Ou seja, ele é mutuamente exclusivo com o `if` anterior, o fato do primeiro ser verdadeiro já garante que o segundo seja falso, então não tem porque avaliá-lo. E para evitar sua avaliação temos que fazer tudo virar um bloco só.

Do jeito que fez funciona, mas é ineficiente porque ele vai avaliar sem necessidade. Tem caso que não funciona (depende da condição). Então vamos melhorá-lo?

```
@if (item.Recursos == "Usuario") {
    <p style="font-size: 14px; font-weight:bold;">Usuario Criado:</p>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UsuarioCriado, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
} else if (item.Recursos == "E-mail") {
    <p style="font-size: 14px; font-weight:bold;">E-mail Criado:</p>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailCriado, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
}
```

Então agora ele só vai avaliar o segundo se o primeiro der falso, ou executa um bloco **ou** executa o outro, nunca poderá fazer os dois, que é o que desejamos. Melhorou.

Notou que o `else`não precisa do `@`. Usando Razor dá pra entender até melhor que isso tudo é um bloco só.

Agora podemos analisar o próximo `if`. Ele é mutuamente exclusivo em relação aos anteriores, então podemos fazer a mesma coisa com ele e os demais.

```
@if (item.Recursos == "Usuario") {
    <p style="font-size: 14px; font-weight:bold;">Usuario Criado:</p>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UsuarioCriado, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
} else if (item.Recursos == "E-mail") {
    <p style="font-size: 14px; font-weight:bold;">E-mail Criado:</p>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailCriado, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
} else if (item.Recursos == "Desktop" || item.Recursos == "Desktop (Novo") {
    <p style="font-size: 14px; font-weight:bold;">Nome do Desktop:</p>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NomeDesktop, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
} else if (item.Recursos == "Notebook")
    <p style="font-size: 14px; font-weight:bold;">Nome do Notebook:</p>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NomeNotebook, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/IfElse.cs).

Agora só entra em um deles, todos são mutualmente exclusivos, sendo que um deles aceita duas variações ao mesmo tempo (tem um `||`) . Se pensar bem o uso do `else` é igual a um `||`, porque ambos possuem uma coisa chamada [curto-circuito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/363837/101), ou seja, quando um se torna verdeiro não precisa mais avaliar o resto (no caso do `&&` é diferente, mas isso é outro assunto e não tem equivalente com o `else`).

Esta forma garante que só um desses blocos será executado porque ele é tratado como uma coisa única.

Se as verificações fossem independentes, ou seja, qualquer uma poderia ser executada mesmo que outra já tenha sido executada, então não poderia colocar tudo como uma coisa só e o `else` seria inadequado. É tudo questão de entender o problema e fazer o que se espera dele. Tem caso que fazer mais que um seria um problema. Este é um caso que apenas é mais eficiente.

Este é um caso que poderia usar um `switch` porque ele apenas compara sempre a mesma variável apenas verificando a igualdade, exatamente para o que o `if` foi criado. O `switch`tende ser mais eficiente que o `if` quando ele pode ser aplicado.

Eu me preocuparia em alinhar melhor o código e evitar esses comentários. Se eles são úteis é porque o código está complexo demais e deveria dar mais semântica pra eles. Se eles só falam obviedade não os coloque. Eu não os li porque a condição é óbvia demais pra mim, não tem nada que possa acrescentar em comentário que torne mais legível, só está poluindo o código e criando uma potencial violação do [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101). Veja [Por que não comentar o código?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/399158/101).

Answer (score 1):

Resumidamente..

Você deve utilizar o **if** quando seu algoritmo tem a possibilidade de entrar em todos os **ifs**.

Quando o seu algoritmo não deve entrar em multiplos **ifs**, você usa o else **if** ou switch case.

**Else if** acaba sendo mais perfomatico do que multiplos **ifs**, porque quando uma condição é true, ele entra no **if**, executa o trecho de código e ja pula todos os demais **ifs**, pois ele entende que ja fez o trabalho.

No seu caso expecificamente, seria interessante utilizar switch case, pois você está verificando a mesma variável **item.Recursos**

Answer (score 0):

Pra exemplificar com algo comparado no seu dia a dia, imagina a situação:

Você está no mercado, e quer comprar apenas um chocolate, sonho de valsa ou diamante negro. Mas você não sabe qual está na promoção.

Então você usaria `if` e `if else`. Neste caso, você compraria apenas um chocolate.

Agora, Você está no mercado, e quer comprar os dois chocolates se estiverem na promoção.

Então você usaria dois `if` nessa situação. Podendo comprar os dois chocolates, caso estivessem em promoção.